# xamarin app crashes when the primary key is added to the existing sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, primary-key

I have a table named "Log" with some string and int columns.
App is installed and working on a device.

I recently added primary key, to the existing int column as follows.

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int MobileID { get; set; }
```

If i update the old app with the newly built, then it crashes.

How to handle this addition of primary key?

Thanks

Comment: if you change the schema of an existing table, you'll need to take some steps to update the table schema when the app is updated.  It won't magically do that on its own.

Comment: can you send me an example link or any good article?

Comment: @sai - In new release, you can get the current data from the above mentioned table to a temp table and delete and recreate the table and insert the data into the table from temp table. This should be a one time process.